# Angular FileSaver zip file corrupted. Related to Encoding

Tags: angular, encoding, clojure, zip, filesaver.js

I am using Angular HttpClient. Get to download a zip file from server.

**Angular Code:**

```
httpHeaders = ({
  'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  'tonic_id': this.getTonicToken()
});

observe: 'response',
headers: httpHeaders,
params: httpParams,
responseType: 'arraybuffer',
withCredentials: true
```

**To save the zip file:**

```
saveAs(new Blob([fileData], {type: "application/zip"}), "test.zip");
```

**Server code is written in clojure:**

```
(defresource download
  [db userid target]
  resource/base-resource
  :allowed-methods [:get]
  :available-media-type ["application/zip"]
  :handle-ok (fn [_]
               (try
                 (ring-response {:status  200
                                 :headers {"Content-Type" "application/zip"}
                                 :body    (io/file
                                            (:csv-dir (config/app-config))
                                            (export-db/file-name-from-uuid
                                              (:connection db)
                                              userid (first (str/split target #"\."))))})
                 (catch Throwable t (error t) (throw t))))
  :exists? (file-exists? db userid (first (str/split target #"\."))))
```

I am able to download the zip file, but not able to unzip it. When comparing the zip file on the server with the created one, I noticed many squares in the new zip file. I assume it has something to do encoding.

Please help. see image below:

[image]